# How do I lower a variable by a certain value every second in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this countdown script that I made in react that calculates the time until an event and it works fine, but I want it to recalculate every 1 second to check for updates and such. How do I do this, code inserted below..

```
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
// ...
export function GetLaunchCountdown(time) {

    // Get launch time
    const launchTime = DateTime.fromISO(time.time); 
    // Get current time
    const currentTime = DateTime.now()
    // Calculate time difference
    const timeDiff = launchTime.diff(currentTime)


    const timeDiffMili = timeDiff.toMillis()

    var displayTime = DateTime.fromMillis(timeDiffMili)
    if (timeDiff.toMillis() > 86400000) {
        // Display with days
        return(<>{displayTime.toFormat("dd:hh:mm:ss")}</>)
    } else {
        // Display with hours
        return(<>{displayTime.toFormat("hh:mm:ss")}</>)
    }  
}
// ...
```

It would be easiest to just subtract from the `timeDiffMili` variable (that's why it's there).

Comment: Why not use setInterval?

Comment: @AminDarian It's react.. I gotta use something like useState but I got no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the current time in the **state**. Use a timing function, like `setInterval` to change the state. Trigger that timing function inside a `useEffect` function so that you get a single interval running (and don't start a new one ever rerender). Return a function that clears the interval when the component is unmounted.

```
    const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(DateTime.now())

    useEffect( () => {
        const update = () => {
            setCurrentTime(DateTime.now());
        }

        const interval = setInterval(update, 500);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);
```